# MySQL end SUBSTRING with sentence

Tags: mysql, substring

Here is my example. When I run this query:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vitae odio tellus, sit amet facilisis neque. Cras sapien nulla, suscipit non imperdiet ac, aliquet vitae lectus. Nulla a varius dolor. Nunc convallis, augue et fermentum volutpat, lectus urna sagittis risus, vel iaculis diam est convallis lectus. Suspendisse potenti. Morbi malesuada tristique varius.', 1, 300)
```

I get the first 300 chars of the sentence. That is good. Except that I want it to end where the last dot (.) is in the result.

So the query result is this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vitae odio tellus, sit amet facilisis neque. Cras sapien nulla, suscipit non imperdiet ac, aliquet vitae lectus. Nulla a varius dolor. Nunc convallis, augue et fermentum volutpat, lectus urna sagittis risus, vel iaculis diam est convalli
```

But I want it to be this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vitae odio tellus, sit amet facilisis neque. Cras sapien nulla, suscipit non imperdiet ac, aliquet vitae lectus. Nulla a varius dolor.
```

Can I do that with a MySQL query, and how?

Tnx

---

UPDATE 1,
This is what I had so far:

```
SET @longtext = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vitae odio tellus, sit amet facilisis neque. Cras sapien nulla, suscipit non imperdiet ac, aliquet vitae lectus. Nulla a varius dolor. Nunc convallis, augue et fermentum volutpat, lectus urna sagittis risus, vel iaculis diam est convallis lectus. Suspendisse potenti. Morbi malesuada tristique varius.';

SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(
    @longtext,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(
        SUBSTRING(
            @longtext,
            1,
            300
        ),
        '.',
        -1
    )
    , 1
);
```

---

UPDATE 2,
Tnx @Ben

My solution is:

```
SET @longtext = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vitae odio tellus, sit amet facilisis neque. Cras sapien nulla, suscipit non imperdiet ac, aliquet vitae lectus. Nulla a varius dolor. Nunc convallis, augue et fermentum volutpat, lectus urna sagittis risus, vel iaculis diam est convallis lectus. Suspendisse potenti. Morbi malesuada tristique varius.';

SELECT SUBSTRING(
    @longtext,
    1,
    300 - ifnull(
        LOCATE(
            '.',
            REVERSE(
                SUBSTRING(
                    @longtext,
                    1,
                    300
                )
            )
        ),
    1)
);
```

Comment: So you don't want to use substring at all then? You want to select everything?

Comment: is 300 chars the max or min substring length?

Comment: @Ben, No, I want to substring the substring if you catch my drift :)

Comment: @Veritas, I don't know. For now it is the max, but that can vary. I have a solution, although I think it's not realy good. Wait one minute so I can post it!

Comment: You want to do something like LOCATE(".", reverse('string')) to find the position of the last dot.  I recommend doing string manipulation stuff in application code level, in PHP or JAVA.

Comment: I get you @iSenne, you're looking to find the index position of the nth occurrence of a string within another.

Comment: @Yada Yes, but that would be the easy way haha. I would like to choose to do this in MySQL so that I maintain a proper structure in my PHP code!

Comment: @Ben, Exectly. As you can see in my example, that is how I want it. But I don't know if this is the right way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I think I've got it; comments are unfortunately in reverse due to the nature of the thing...

```
select substr('my_string', 1
            -- 300 - distance from the first '.' in the reversed string.
             , 300 - ifnull(
                           -- Get the 1st position of the '.' in the
                           -- reversed string.
                            locate('.', reverse(substr('my_string',1,300))
                                  )
                          -- if it's null, i.e. doesn't exist, replace it with 1.
                           , 1)
              )
```

You can change the 300 as you wish.

Answer (score 2):

I tried this but i think is kind of complex, but It worked.

```
DECLARE @BEGIN INT;
DECLARE @END INT;
DECLARE @TEXT VARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @DELIMITER VARCHAR(MAX);
SET @BEGIN = 1;
SET @END = 300;
SET @DELIMITER = '.'

SET @TEXT = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vitae odio tellus, sit amet facilisis neque. Cras sapien nulla, suscipit non imperdiet ac, aliquet vitae lectus. Nulla a varius dolor. Nunc convallis, augue et fermentum volutpat, lectus urna sagittis risus, vel iaculis diam est convallis lectus. Suspendisse potenti. Morbi malesuada tristique varius.'
--SELECT    SUBSTRING(@TEXT, @END-1, 1)
WHILE SUBSTRING(@TEXT, @END, 1) <> @DELIMITER
BEGIN
    IF SUBSTRING(@TEXT, @END-1, 1) = @DELIMITER
    BEGIN
            SELECT  SUBSTRING(@TEXT, @BEGIN, @END-1)
            BREAK;
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @END = @END -1  
        CONTINUE    
    END
END
```

Comment: This is complex indeed. I don't think that I can use it because the end (300) can vary!

Comment: well, it is a option, you can make it a function to receive the string, beginning , end and delimiter and it should work..

Comment: True, but I am not yet familiar with this kind of query's (I see my coworker do this, and it scares the crap out of my haha)

Comment: hahahahah xD, well i cant figure out another way, thought that @bassam answered would work xD, as I said it is kind of complex, and indeed it is not the best answer but can help you to archieve your objective

Comment: I went with the solution from @Ben. Tnx for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

`select reverse( substring( reverse( 'Lorem String' ), locate( '.', reverse( 'Lorem String' ) ) ) )`

Where 'Lorem String' is your big long string above.

Comment: Your example would return null: `substr('string',0)`

Comment: Not quite yet, although I am going to look at the REVERSE in MySQL

Answer (score 1):

A working example from my table:

SELECT substr(notes,1,(301-(LOCATE('.',REVERSE(substr(notes,1,300)))))) FROM accounts where id='4'

Original text string in my database that is 480 characters (32 character sentances x 15 entries)

```
"This sentence is 32 characters. This sentence is 32 characters. This sentence is 32 characters. This sentence is 32 characters. This sentence is 32 characters. This sentence is 32 characters. This sentence is 32 characters. This sentence is 32 characters. This sentence is 32 characters. This sentence is 32 characters. This sentence is 32 characters. This sentence is 32 characters. This sentence is 31 characters. This sentence is 32 characters. This sentence is 32 characters. "
```

Result of query is 287 characters because the 10th sentence was too long to fit with the period included:

```
"This sentence is 32 characters. This sentence is 32 characters. This sentence is 32 characters. This sentence is 32 characters. This sentence is 32 characters. This sentence is 32 characters. This sentence is 32 characters. This sentence is 32 characters. This sentence is 32 characters."
```

ugly .. but it works.

Comment: "SELECT substr(notes,1,(301-(LOCATE('.',REVERSE(substr(notes,1,300)))))), notes FROM accounts where id='4'" works for 300 characters as expected ..

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vitae odio tellus, sit amet facilisis neque. Cras sapien nulla, suscipit non imperdiet ac, aliquet vitae lectus. Nulla a varius dolor. Nunc convallis, augue et fermentum volutpat, lectus urna sagittis risus, vel iaculis diam est convallis lectus. Suspendisse potenti. Morbi malesuada tristique varius.', 1, 300),'.',-1) + '.'
```

Comment: No, I tried this. But in this case I would get the string after the last dot!